# Show month of a file's creation (Grouping files by quadrant of creation)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to group files by the quadrant of their creation.
What I'm trying to do is determine when a file was created - for example, if I had a file that looks like this:

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  208 Aug 30 16:24 q.sh`

I'd like the output to be nothing but the month it was created - in this case, `8`.

Once I figure this value out, I can toss it into a simple case statement which will sort it - currently I came up with this:

```
#FILE_DATE would be the value I figure out above
case $FILE_DATE in
 [1-3])
        echo "Quadrant 1"
        ;;
[4-6])
        echo "Quadrant 2"
        ;;
[7-9])
        echo "Quadrant 3"
        ;;
[10-12])
        echo "Quadrant 4"
        ;;
esac
```

I've tried using the `stat` command, as well as filtering output of `ls`, but have not figured out how to do this reliably.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: File creation time is not stored in most UNIX/Linux filesystems.

Comment: Additionally in this context `[10-12]` is equivalent to `[0-12]`. It matches a *single character*, in this case `0`, `1`, `2` or any character between `0` and `1` in the current locale. Usually `0` directly precedes `1`, so the whole expression is equivalent to `[012]` and matches `0`, `1` or `2` only. You probably want `1[0-2]` or straightforward `10|11|12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `date`, you can do:

```
quadrant=$(( $(date -r "$file" +'(%-m - 1) / 3 + 1') ))
```

To get the *quadrant* in which a file was last modified.

In `zsh`, you could add a `byquadrant` glob sort order as:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
byquadrant() {
  local month
  stat -A month -F %-m +mtime -- ${1-$REPLY}
  REPLY=$(( (month - 1) / 3 + 1 ))-$REPLY
}
```

To use as:

```
ls -ldU -- *(o+byquadrant)
```

for instance (here using GNU `ls`'s `-U` to disable `ls`'s own sorting) to sort by *quadrant*, and then by filename within the same quadrant.

The `byquadrant` function returns a string that is made of the quadrant number followed by `-` and the original file name, and that's what we tell zsh to `o`rder that glob om using the `o+<functionname>` glob qualifier.

For symlinks, `zsh`'s `stat` (like GNU `date -r`) by default retrieves the mtime of the *target* of the symlink. Add `-L` if you want the mtime of the symlink itself.

If you wanted to use the GNU implementation of `stat` (which postdates `zsh`'s by a few years and is incompatible, and even incompatible with GNU `find`'s `-printf` which predates it by decades and is much less usable), you'd need to output it in one of the two timestamp formats it support (iso8601 or raw epoch time) and extract the month some other way.

Could be for instance with GNU `date` again:

```
quadrant=$(( $(
    set -o pipefail
    stat -c%y -- "$file" | date -f - +'(%-m - 1) / 3 + 1'
  ) ))
```

Note that GNU `stat` by default gets you the mtime of the symlink instead of its target (the opposite of `zsh` `stat`). `-L` to change it.

It also doesn't work for a file called `-`.

With recent versions of GNU `stat` on recent versions of Linux, you can also use `%w` instead of `%y` to get the *birth time* of the file where available (as displayed with recent versions of GNU `ls` with `ls -l --time=birth`), though I find it's less useful as a *creation* time than the *last modification time* (which can be seen as the creation time of the *contents* of the file).